# Mobile locator using cellphone number?

Tags: web-services, algorithm, mobile, gps

I want to know if it is possible to get the current location of mobile phone using mobile number . Can you suggest me any algorithm. I want to create a web service and integrate it with Google maps.

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible.  Even for the carriers, it isn't possible to get GPS-based coordinates for an arbitrary device referenced by phone number, for obvious privacy reasons.

You need software on the device to report the location.  At that point, you might as well use some pre-existing software, such as Google Latitude (for Android).  There are many solutions out there.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the carrier can find out which cell tower a phone is connected to. They won't divulge that info, though, unless you're police.

Comment: Yes, they can certainly find your general location, but as my answer states, they cannot find your *GPS-based coordinates* unless the phone is configured to share that information (such as during an emergency call).